# Logical python question - handling directories and files in them

Tags: python

I'm using this function to extract files from .zip archive and store it on the server:

```
def unzip_file_into_dir(file, dir):
    import sys, zipfile, os, os.path

    os.makedirs(dir, 0777)
    zfobj = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    for name in zfobj.namelist():
        if name.endswith('/'):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(dir, name))
        else:
            outfile = open(os.path.join(dir, name), 'wb')
            outfile.write(zfobj.read(name))
            outfile.close()
```

And the usage:

```
unzip_file_into_dir('/var/zips/somearchive.zip', '/var/www/extracted_zip')
```

somearchive.zip have this structure:

```
somearchive.zip
    1.jpeg
    2.jpeg
    another.jpeg
```

or, somethimes, this one:

```
somearchive.zip
    somedir/
        1.jpeg
        2.jpeg
        another.jpeg
```

Question is: **how do I modify my function, so that my `extracted_zip` catalog would always contain just images, not images in another subdirectory, even if images are stored in `somedir` inside an archive.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
outfile = open(os.path.join(dir, os.path.basename(name)), 'wb')
```

to strip the path from the name of the ZIP entry. This way, only the filename is left and you don't get any directories. You must also comment out the `os.mkdir()` or replace it with `pass`.